# Show Reviewers filter keeps getting reset to All Reviewers in Word 2003

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a Word document open in Word 2003 SP3. Change tracking is on and two authors have worked on the document.

Using the reviewing toolbar, I filtered the changes I wanted to see to a single reviewer by using the Show menu and selecting Reviewers and then clearing the selection for the reviewer whose changes I do not want to see highlighted. This works to hide the other reviewers changes temporarily.

If I click my mouse in the document and then scroll the document, the reviewers filter is reset to to All Reviewers.

Has anyone seen this? Is there a fix or a workaround?

(Please no cracks about using an ancient version of the app).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a solution, but a workaround that kept me from going insane: (probably in a separate copy of the doc) hide the reviewer you want to see and show all others, then "Accept all changes shown". You'll end up with only the changes by the reviewer you want to see, so toggle the filter to show that reviewer, and you're sort-of-there.

Makes you wonder WTF is the point of those filters...

Comment: thanks. Fortunately, since this post I've upgraded to office 2010. I must say it fixed many of these types of annoyances that I had learned to work around in 2003.